# udev rules not working

Tags: udev, networkmanager

I am trying to change the name of my network device `wlan0` to `eth1` in order to get Matlab to active, I have added the file: `70-use-eth1-for-matlab-licensing.rules` with the following contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTRS{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", ATTRS{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTRS{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth?", NAME="eth1"
```

to the folder `/etc/udev/rules.d` but after rebooting, the device is still called `wlan0`.

I know that this question has been asked many times on here, but looking at answers to previous questions has not enabled me to fix my problem. What am I missing?

Comment: is 50...4b your MAC address, or the one from the sample file?

Comment: Mine... i've edited it to remove it

Comment: contact Matlab's technical support.  Or switch to Octave which doesn't have stupid licensing issues.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084246/differences-between-octave-and-matlab and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Differences_between_Octave_and_MATLAB